# How to pass a value from a strongly typed view to a strongly typed partial view with a different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this strongly typed view that renders a dataTable using ajax and i have this strongly typed partial view in a modal that has a different model than the parent view but has a common member. What i can't seem to do is pass a specific value to the partial view.

Parent View Model:

```
@model IEnumerable<MobileNumbers>
```

MobileNumbers Model:

```
  public class MobileNumbers : BaseEntity
{
    public long mobileNumberId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(09|\+639)\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Number Format")]
    public string mobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Provider")]
    public long providerId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hired?")]
    public bool hired { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resigned?")]
    public bool resigned { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Blocked?")]
    public bool blocked { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Terminated?")]
    public bool terminated { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Walk - In Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime dateWalkIn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Uploaded")]
    public DateTime dateUploaded { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Uploader")]
    public long uploadedBy { get; set; }

    public int totalCount {get; set; }

    public int totalRecords {get; set; }

    public MobileNumbers(){
        mobileNumberId = 0;
        mobileNumber = String.Empty;
        providerId = 0;
        hired = false;
        resigned = false;
        blocked = false;
        active = true;
        terminated = false;
        dateWalkIn = DateTime.Now;
        dateUploaded = DateTime.Now;
        uploadedBy = 0;

    totalCount = 0;
    totalRecords = 0;
    }
```

What I use to call the Partial View:

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml",new SMSSendModels());}
```

Partial View Model:

```
@model SMSSendModels
```

SMSSendModels

```
    public SMSInventory smsInventory { get; set; }
    public SmsContent SmsContent { get; set; }
    public MobileNumbers mobileNumbers {get; set;}
    public SmsInventoryUpload smsInventoryUpload { get; set; }
```

SMS Inventory

```
 [Display(Name="SMS Txn ID")]
    public long smsId { get; set; }
    public long smsContentId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="SMS Title")]
    public string smsContentTitle { get; set; }
    public long mobileNumberId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(09|\+639)\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Number Format")]
    public string mobileNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Comments")]
    public string comments { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Uploader")]
    public long uploadedBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Date Sent")]
    public DateTime dateSent { get; set; }
            public int totalCount {get; set; }
    public int totalRecords {get; set; }

    public SMSInventory(){
        smsId = 0;
        smsContentId = 0;
        smsContentTitle = String.Empty;
        comments = String.Empty;
        uploadedBy = 0;
        dateSent = DateTime.Now;

    totalCount = 0;
    totalRecords = 0;
    }
```

SMSSendModels contain both the model MobileNumbers and SMSInventory which has a common member of a string mobileNumber.

So what i want to do is to either pass the model MobileNumbers into the partial view or just pass the value of mobileNumber into the partialView

Comment: Pls post your SMSSendModels class

Comment: please add both MobileNumbers and SMSSendModels models

Answer (score 1):

You just need make Viewmodal that contain both of classes inside

```
 public class SMSSendModels 
{
    public MobileNumbers mobileModal { get; set; }
    public SMSInventory InventoryModal { get; set; }
}
```

Inside to your controller you can return viewmodal or either you can pass mobileNumber or SMSinventory

```
 SMSSendModels vm = new SMSSendModels ();

 vm.mobileModal = // assign data to
 vm.InventoryModal = // assign data to 


  // Return as what you want inside to your partial view
  return vm
```

Inside your View :

```
   @model WebApp.Models.SMSSendModels 

//either you can use 1st modal / 2nd modal or Both you can use


//1st modal
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 last-cb">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.mobileModal.fieldname, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(mbox => mbox.mobileModal.fieldname, "", new { })
  </div>

 //2nd modal
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.InventoryModal.fieldname, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                            @*<label>Captions</label>*@
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InventoryModal.fieldname, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxLength = "25" })
                                        </div>
```

I hope this will help .. still you are facing problem you can comment below

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, if the child view is in another controller will the same solution work?

Comment: idn't undserstand , please elaborate in more detail